# Array of strings won't print

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop, scanf

I'm making a program where a teacher can enter the number of students and their full name. I don't know what I'm doing wrong because this is the first time I'm trying to print an array of strings. This is the part of my program that I'm having trouble with:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n_students,i,b=1;
    char surname[20],first_name[20];

    printf("number of students:");
    scanf("%d",&n_students);

    for(i=0;i<n_students;i++)
    {
        printf("%d. ",b);
        scanf("%s %s",&surname[i],&first_name[i]);
    }
    for(i=0;i<n_students;i++)
    {
        printf("%s, %s",first_name[i],surname[i]);
    }
}
```

this part is what Im having trouble with. pls help

```
    for(i=0;i<n_students;i++)
    {
        printf("%s, %s",first_name[i],surname[i]);
    }
```

Comment: You dont have an array of strings, you have an array of char (i.e. "one string") your code will overwrite the names (except for the first letter)

Comment: Hint : strings in C are array of characters.Now try.

Comment: You can simply fix it by replacing %s with %c in your loop. Because you don't need an array of strings but an array of chars.

Answer (score 4):

`printf("%s, %s",first_name[i],surname[i]);` invokes *undefined behavior* because it is passing `char` where `char*` is required.

You have only two strings, not array of strings.

Fixed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_STUDENT_NUM 1024

int main(void)
{
    int n_students,i,b=1;
    /* allocate arrays of (arrays to store) strings */
    char surname[MAX_STUDENT_NUM][20],first_name[MAX_STUDENT_NUM][20];

    printf("number of students:");
    /* check if scanf() is successful */
    if(scanf("%d",&n_students) != 1)
    {
        fputs("number read failed\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
    /* check the number to avoid buffer overrun */
    if(n_students > (int)(sizeof(surname) / sizeof(*surname)))
    {
        fputs("too many students\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }

    for(i=0;i<n_students;i++)
    {
        printf("%d. ",b);
        /* remove & and limit length to read to avoid buffer overrun */
        /* check if scanf() is successful */
        if(scanf("%19s %19s",surname[i],first_name[i]) != 2)
        {
            fputs("failed to read names\n", stderr);
            return 1;
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<n_students;i++)
    {
        printf("%s, %s",first_name[i],surname[i]);
    }
}
```